# Где определяемое слово, а где приложение?

Tags: приложение

•   Субстантивные определения в повести Паустовского "О жизни":

1. Каждый вечер в кафе входил, протирая запотевшие выпуклые очки и натыкаясь сослепу на столики, известный московский книголюб журналист Щелкунов.

При определяемом слове книголюб находится распространенное приложение журналист Щелкунов, внутри которого, в свою очередь, определяемое слово Щелкунов имеет при себе в препозиции по отношению к определяемому слову одиночное необособленное приложение журналист.

В «Повести о жизни» К.Г. Паустовского распространенные необособленные приложения в препозиции встречаются при определяемом слове – собственном имени лица:

2. Это было в дни убийства германского посла графа Мирбаха.

В первом предложении определяемое слово - книголюб, а приложение - журналист Щелкунов.

Во втором предложении определяемое слово - граф Мирбах, а приложение - германского посла.

Как определить, где приложение, а где определяемое слово?

Answer (score 3):

Это тема **неоднородных приложений**, например:

Мой друг писатель **Васильев**   жил тогда в Москве. Научную работу возглавил заведующий кафедрой профессор **Сорокин А.А.**

В этих примерах имя собственное - это определяемое слово, к нему относятся **два приложения**, одно из них имеет согласованное или несогласованное  определение.

Соответственно: (московский книголюб) (журналист) **Щелкунов**, (германский посол) (граф) **Мирбах**.